# "Такой как" - когда запятая ставится перед словом «такой»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Грамота.ру поясняет:
В некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:
1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в старинных замках (ср.: Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках);
2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется): Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.

Мой вопрос: почему в п. 1 речь идет только о прилагательных. Действует ли это правило, если вместо прилагательного стоит другое определение? Например: Погода, навевающая тоску, такая(,) как осенью.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Сравнительный оборот может входить **в составные союзы и союзные выражения** ТАК ЖЕ КАК, ТАК ЖЕ КАК И, ТАКОЙ ЖЕ КАК, ТАКОЙ КАК, ТАКОЙ ЖЕ КАК И.

Там **еще одна** станция за переходом, **такая же как эта**, как будто отражение в зеркале.  **Еще** победа, **такая же как и вчерашняя**: гвардейские войска выбили турок из Этрополя. **Наша** группа, **так же как и параллельная**, сдала все зачеты.

Во всех этих примерах признак уже назван или предмет **уже упомянут, а далее следует его пояснение.**

2) Для сравнения: (1) Погода **такая,** как осенью. (2) Погода **дождливая**, такая как осенью. (Местоимение "такая" (1) и прилагательное дождливая (2) в роли именной части сказуемого).

3) Погода, навевающая тоску, такая как осенью.

Здесь **не в прилагательном или причастии дело, а в обособленном  обороте, который стоит на месте сказуемого**. Тогда надо считать предложение назывным с двумя определениями.